# How Do I Bind Different Concretes to a Property Using StructureMap

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

They use StructureMap for IoC where I am currently working.

I have an application class that will implement multiple properties of the same interface...and I need to bind DIFFERENT IMPLEMENTATIONS

...and no, I cannot do this: `IProvider<T>`

FOR INSTANCE:

```
    public class MyApplication
    {
        [SetterProperty]
        public IProvider OneProvider { get; set; }

        [SetterProperty]
        public IProvider TwoProvider { get; set; }
    }

    public class FooProvider: IProvider {
        // I would like to force this one to bind-on OneProvider ...
    }
    public class BarProvider: IProvider {
        // I would like to force this one to bind-on TwoProvider ...
    }
```

In Unity, there are many ways to do this, for instance;

```
[Dependency("FooProvider")]
public IProvider OneProvider { get; set; }

[Dependency("BarProvider")]
public IProvider TwoProvider { get; set; }
```

**...however, StructureMaps SetterProperty attribute doesnt allow for this.**

**QUESTION:** 
How do I bind different implementations into an instance-property?

**SAMPLE REGISTRY:** 
Here is an example of what my registry might look like...

```
public ContainerRegistry()
{
    Scan(
        scan =>
        {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            scan.LookForRegistries();
            scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(f => f.FullName.StartsWith("My.Awesome.Company", true, null));
            scan.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IApplication));
            scan.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IManager<>));
            scan.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IProvider));
            scan.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IUnitOfWorkFactory<>));
            scan.SingleImplementationsOfInterface();
        });

    For(typeof(IApplication)).Use(typeof(MyApplication));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

According to documentation, you can use [Inline Setter Configuration](http://structuremap.github.io/setter-injection/)

> the setter policies in the next section can still be filled by
>   StructureMap if an inline dependency is configured matching that
>   setter property as shown in the example below:

```
public class MyApplication : IApplication {
    public IProvider OneProvider { get; set; }
    public IProvider TwoProvider { get; set; }
}


public class RuleWithSettersRegistry : Registry {
    public RuleWithSettersRegistry() {

        //...other code removed for brevity

        For<IApplication>().Use<MyApplication>()
            // I would like to force FooProvider to bind-on OneProvider        
            .Setter(x => x.OneProvider).Is<FooProvider>()
            // I would like to force BarProvider to bind-on TwoProvider
            .Setter(x => x.TwoProvider).Is<BarProvider>();            
    }
}
```

---

### Original Answer

If you are able to modify the implementations and the target class then try to differentiate the intended dependencies.

```
public interface IFooProvider : IProvider { }

public interface IFooProvider : IProvider { }
```

Have the implementations

```
public class MyApplication {
    [SetterProperty]
    public IFooProvider OneProvider { get; set; }

    [SetterProperty]
    public IBarProvider TwoProvider { get; set; }
}

public class FooProvider: IFooProvider { }

public class BarProvider: IBarProvider { }
```

That way when registering all `IProvider` derived implementations with

```
scan.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IProvider));
```

it will grab the intended implementations and bind them.